# How to transform a dataframe into time series?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I'm sorry , i know this question has been asked a lot of times , but I'm having problems to convert my dataframe into time series.

this is my dataframe ( after dropping some columns):

```
  head(New_DF):

       ï..date   qty
    1 2017-07-05  61
    2 2018-01-20  73
    3 2017-07-10 145
    4 2017-07-01 255
    5 2017-05-23 267
    6 2017-06-24 242
```

And this is what i did:

```
    library(zoo)

    as.ts(read.zoo(New_Df, FUN = as.yearmon))
```

And i get this Error:

```
    Error in seq.default(head(tt, 1), tail(tt, 1), deltat) : 
   'from' must be a finite number
   In addition: Warning message:
   In zoo(rval3, ix) :
   some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique
```

I think i got why , it is because i have a lot of duplicates in my i..date column , unfortunately i don't want to drop them since time-series ML Model are bit different than other routine ML models. As time-series model is based upon the sequence of previous values, dropping a Date may impact my solution.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated , thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) yearmon** Assuming `New_DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, use `read.zoo` specifying the argument `aggregate=sum` .

```
library(zoo)
read.zoo(New_DF, FUN = as.yearmon, aggregate = sum)
```

giving:

```
May 2017 Jun 2017 Jul 2017 Jan 2018 
     267      242      461       73
```

**2) Date** If you want to keep the individual rows then use `Date` class instead of `yearmon` (assuming that the dates are unique).

```
read.zoo(New_DF)
## 2017-05-23 2017-06-24 2017-07-01 2017-07-05 2017-07-10 2018-01-20 
##        267        242        255         61        145         73
```

**3) sequence number** Another possibility is to just ignore the dates and use 1, 2, .3, ..

```
zoo(New_DF$qty)
##   1   2   3   4   5   6 
## 267 242 255  61 145  73
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "      ï..date   qty
    1 2017-07-05  61
    2 2018-01-20  73
    3 2017-07-10 145
    4 2017-07-01 255
    5 2017-05-23 267
    6 2017-06-24 242 "
New_DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you share some background about your data. Also if there are some duplicates in the data, can you just sum them up, so that the above error won't occur.